# How to avoid &#39; in the sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, character-encoding

I am using MYSQL 5.5. May I know how to avoid `&#39;` in the SQL query? Below is my example query:

```html
<?php
$mySelect1 = "'Ahli Majlis'";
$bracket_mySelect1 = "($mySelect1)";
SQL = "SELECT * FROM user where 1 and nama_gelaran in ".$bracket_mySelect1."";
?>
```

The wrong result I have checked in the console log data is `SELECT * FROM user where 1 and nama_gelaran in (&#39;Ahli Majlis&#39;)`

Actually I want the result is `SELECT * FROM user where 1 and nama_gelaran in ('Ahli Majlis')`

What I tried, but it doesn't work:

```html
SQL = SELECT * FROM user where 1 and nama_gelaran in ".html_entity_decode(htmlentities($bracket_mySelect1,ENT_QUOTES),ENT_QUOTES); .";
```

Comment: This is PHP issue - it replaces chars with entities.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure how you are executing the queries but it is best practice to use PDO rather then the mysql_ functions. This also improves security and protects against mysql injection.

Below is a sample of how to connect and run a PDO query. I have changed your `IN` to be `=` as it looks like you are only passing one value.

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb";
$user = "dbUsername";
$passwd = "dbPassword";

$name = 'Ahli Majlis';

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $passwd);
$stm = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE nama_gelaran = :name");
$stm->bindParam('name', $name);

$user = $stm->fetch();

print_r($user);
```

Answer (score 1):

`&#39;` does *not* come from MySQL *unless* that is what you `INSERTed`.  It does come from certain PHP functions such as htmlentities.  It is `'`.